# UWP convert RAW 8 Bit to PNG

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am developing an app for UWP, we have a scanner connected that provide images in RAW8Bit, we are looking to convert RAW8Bit to PNG files. We manage to do that by converting to Bitmap first, but we need another way to convert directly from RAW to PNG

Comment: What do you mean by "directly from RAW to PNG"?

Comment: @Mailosz, I mean raw 8 bit image array to png byte[] to store as file.

Comment: Do you know the width and height?

Answer (score 2):

You should sure the image width and height and the byte list format is Bgra8.

The Bgra8 means that a pixel is 8 bit and the first byte is blue color...

You can use BitmapEncoder to encode the byte list to png file.

```
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, file);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint) width, (uint) height, 96,
                96, byteList);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
```

Write the code to save to file.

```
    private async Task SaveToFileAsync(byte[] byteList, int width, int height, IStorageFile file)
    {
        using (var stream = (await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()).AsRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await ByteToPng(byteList, width, height, stream);
        }
    }

    private async Task ByteToPng(byte[] byteList, int width, int height, IRandomAccessStream file)
    {
        try
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, file);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint) width, (uint) height, 96,
                96, byteList);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```